# Set Active Model serializer adapter per method

Tags: ruby-on-rails-5, active-model-serializers

I'm trying to build an api-only app in rails 5. I'm using active model serializer ([AMS](https://rubygems.org/gems/active_model_serializers)).
On my `GET /users` (UsersController#index) endpoint, I want the root json to have a "users" keyword before the json array of users.

If I set an initializer with `ActiveModelSerializers.config.adapter = :json`
 value, then I have the desired behavior.

But then, on the  `GET /users/1` the simple user json comes under the key `user`. I'd like to get rid of this key (in this case) and simply answer the user json as the root json.

The question is: how can I define the AMS adapter on a specific endpoint/response/method? Is that possible?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I should have read the manual :$

To override the "root" key, you have to provide a `root:` argument when you call the `render` method. If you are using the `:json` adapter on an initializer, it would be like this:

`render json: @user, root: "admin"`
This would then generate a json like this:

{
    "admin": {
      "id": 123,
      "email": "email@example.com"
    }
  }

If you want, you could also provide another key after the `root:` to set the adapter, like this: `adapter: :json`

So, the `:attributes` adapter doesn't have a root key. In order to remove the root key, you could do:
`render json: @user, root: "admin", adapter: :attributes`

The official documentation is [here](https://github.com/rails-api/active_model_serializers/blob/0-10-stable/docs/general/rendering.md#overriding-the-root-key) and [here](https://github.com/rails-api/active_model_serializers/blob/0-10-stable/docs/general/serializers.md#root)

Comment: Thanks for noticing :) I updated them to a specific release version instead of the master branch.